# My loop will loop, but it will not display what I want

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have my array, and I want to display the array based on whats inside each object in the array. I have the loops here but I can seem to get the `ctx.fillRect` to work.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var blocks = [];

var rows = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function Block(h, w, x, y, c) {
  this.h = h;
  this.w = w;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.c = c;
}
ctx.fillRect(900, 400, 10, 10)
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    blocks.push(new Block(10, 20, j * 30, i * 30, rows[i]))
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  for (var i = 0, len = blocks.length; i < len; i++) {

    for (var j = 0, len2 = blocks[i].length; j < len2; j++) {

      ctx.fillRect(blocks[i][j].x, blocks[i][j].y, blocks[i][j].w, blocks[i][j].h);

    }
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="can" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Did you try checking blocks[i].length and other properties? It's undefined..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`blocks` isn't a multidimensional array.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var blocks = [];

var rows = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function Block(h, w, x, y, c) {
  this.h = h;
  this.w = w;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.c = c;
}

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    blocks.push(new Block(10, 20, j * 30, i * 30, rows[i]))
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  for (var i = 0, len = blocks.length; i < len; i++) {
      ctx.fillRect(blocks[i].x, blocks[i].y, blocks[i].w, blocks[i].h);
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="can" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that the array was not multidimensional. I guess I just wasnt paying attention.